# PHP - Access MS SQL View and Echo Results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, view

I'm trying to access and read a view from a MS SQL database with PHP.  For now I'm just trying to echo out the results on the screen.  When I test, my page shows nothing at all.
This is what I have:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "username1";
$myPass = "password1";
$myDB = "database1";

//connect to database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select database
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//declare statement
$query = "SELECT ProductId";
$query .= "FROM Inventory ";
$query .= "WHERE UPC='15813658428' and ManufacturerID=465";

//execute the query
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

//display results
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . $row["name"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Often when you get a completely blank output from PHP, it is because the server encountered a problem when parsing or interpetting your code. The best way to deal with this when you are getting no other errors is to strip out (or comment out) large blocks of your code and to use numeric echo statements to verify that the code you have not stripped out is executing. Then slowly add more and more of the code back in.

**In this specific case**, I am guessing that the problem may come down to the spaces after the `?>` in your php file. That can confuse servers. Try removing the `?>` completely.

If that still results in no output, then comment out everything after `$myDB = "database1";`, add an echo statement right before the commenting, and slowly move code back into the uncommented section until you find the line that causes the problem.